# How can I compare A date in share Point list and the system date

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development

Anyone help! I have a date on my share Point list and I would like to compare if its less than the Current date .Then after comparing I want to calculate the number of days between 2 date .

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint has a tricky workaround that allows "Today" function. It is not a perfect workaround but it does the job.

1. First, create a new column in your list with the Column Name "Today" (It doesn't matter what type of column or data it is, this is just a place holder. I created a single line of text column.)
2. Create a new a calculated column and name it as "CurrentDate" (or anything you may prefer). Remember to choose "Date and Time" as the return data type for this calculated column. Your formula must be

> =[Today]

3. The above step will update an old date in your "CurrentDate" column but do not worry about it. To get the actual system current date simply delete the "Today" column that you created in first step. SharePoint automatically takes the reference of today's date when you had put the formula `

> =[Today]

4. Create a new calculated column, example "Days" and the return type must be number. Now put the formula as

> =DATEDIF([ProjectDate], [CurrentDate],"d")

Assuming "ProjectDate" is your date/time column already created in list.

Comment: But Calculated Formulas are only updated when the Item is updated, so what does this [CurrentDate] 'calculate' tomorrow??